# Place HTML underneath a position:fixed element?

Tags: css, position

I have a top banner which is styled `position: fixed`. But then this block the contents coming after the banner in the HTML. I've tried to added a margin to the content following the `fixed` banner, but this is not working well across devices. So how can I place the contents aside from the banner underneath the banner?

Edit: What is especially troublesome is I have an input field underneath the `fixed` banner, so that on a mobile device, the keyboard that pops up pushes the input field into the banner area, and completely hides the input element.

Answer (score 0):

Any element in your HTML that you put `position: fixed` on gets removed from the context of the page, that is it moves to a different stacking context with respect to the rest of the page elements and every element that is made `position: fixed` get itself positioned with respect to the view-port of your browser window. So, did you try adding a `padding-top` to the body & the value should be equals to the height of your fixed element? And then once the padding-top is added make your fixed element `top: 0` & `left: 0`, `width: 100%` so that it is placed at a 100% width of the view-port positioned from the top and then rest of the elements on the page will display at a space equals to the height of the fixed element, from the top.

Comment: How best to calculate the height of the fixed element which may change on different devices/viewports.

Comment: Normally the elements that we make fixed on the view-port have a certain height, that we don't like to change often on different screen resolutions. For eg: Header - header can have a logo, nav items etc. and the size for these don't change drastically on different screen sizes so, keeping a defined height for your fixed item would work. But still if the height of your item is changing then you can make use of javascript and call window resize event and then do your thing there.